# Is there a way to chain together Where() statements with OR conditions, as in OrWhere(), in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq - Simulate an OrWhere expression when building LINQ queries dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5428806/linq-simulate-an-orwhere-expression-when-building-linq-queries-dynamically)

I was wondering if anyone can help me.

I know that in entity framework we can chain wheres together so for instance

```
data.Where(x=>x.Id == id ).Where(x=>x.Name == name).Where(x=>x.State == state);
```

so basically the where translates into AND

```
data.Where(x=>x.Id==id && x.Name == name && x.State == state);
```

Is there a way to do the same for OR

```
data.Where(x=>x.Id==id || x.Name == name || x.State == state);
```

could be represented as ...

Answer (score 5):

I think the best way to do this is with [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Comment: Predicate Builder has always worked for me for this exact same situation.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "No" when it comes to out-of-the-box Linq methods, here's why:

I understand the OP deals with `IQueryable<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>`, but the functions available in the former are based on the latter.

`IEnumerable<T>` Linq (or Linq to Objects) works by deferring execution of the various linq methods until the collection is iterated over, even when the iteration begins, it only does the work that is needed to produce the next item in the collection.

Since we're talking about WHERE, we're talking filtering functions. Let's say you have `Base.Where(ConditionA).Where(ConditionB).Where(ConditionC)`. At runtime, this is handled by iterating over the base collection, until it finds the first item that satisfies `ConditionA` and that item is then passed along to the next function. If the item satisfies `ConditionB`, then it is passed along to `ConditionC`, if the item does not satisfy `ConditionB`, then `ConditionB` asks for the next item from `ConditionA`, in order for `ConditionA` to get the next item, it continues to iterate over the `Base` until it finds another item that satisfies `ConditionA`, then `ConditionB` test to see if the new item satisfies it, and so on and so on.

The reason an `.OrWhere()` doesn't exist in this type of workflow is that the previous statement would need to have knowledge that it is passing it's result to such a function, and it will essentially need to pass every item it comes across along (even if the condition isn't satisfied), but then also pass long whether it was satisfied or not. This adds a great deal of complexity to an otherwise simple operation.

Hope this helps...